# Escalizar barra vertical (Valores negativos - positivos)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola un gran saludo comunidad inteligente ! Muy agradecido con todo el conocimiento que he adquirido en este sitio, y el día de hoy vengo con una nueva duda.

Tengo un código en HTML,CSS & JavaScript, donde represento 2 barras graficas con barras verticales. Una barra de graficas contiene valores de 0 a 10 y funciona tal como quiero. Respecto a la segunda barra tengo valores de -50 a 150, mi código lo que hace es escalizar una variable de entrada con valores de 0 a 10 , -50 a 150 y modificar la hoja de estilos en el valor "height" para de acuerdo a las variables de entrada modifique los pixeles del "heigh".

0 a 10    => 0px a 300px  (Funciona)
-50 a 150 => 0px a 300px  (Aun no funciona)

Mi código para la barra grafica 1 que me funciona seria el siguiente :

```
            $('.bars li .bar1').each(function(){

            $(this).css({"height" : pressures[0]/0.033});
```

Mi código para la barra grafica 2 que aun no funciona seria el siguiente :

```
            $('.bars li .tem1').each(function(){

            $(this).css({"height" : temperatures[0]/0.5});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok creo que he encontrado la solución, lo que realmente pretendía era mapear los valores de entrada a los de salida, por lo tanto :

```
-50 ->  0 px
150 ->  300 px
```

Pensé que al tener valores negativos la formula de mapeo no funcionaria, pero realmente tenia un error en la sintaxis de la formula, así que voy a postear la formula que me funciono.

```
let in_min = -50;
let in_max = 150;
let out_min= 0;
let out_max= 300;
let in;
let out;

out = (in - in_min)*(out_max - out_min)/(in_max - in_min) + out_min ;
out = (in - (-50))*(300 - 0) / (150 - (-50)) + 0 ;
```